# How can I get notified of internal item moves inside a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, notifications, qtreewidget

I subclassed a QTreeWidget, set its *dragDropMode* to *InternalMove* and populated it with custom items, some of which can be dragged, others accept drops. The user can move items around the tree as expected. But I need to be notified of the change in the order of items and react appropriately. Unfortunately, there are no signals associated with the movement of items inside the tree that I could connect to.

I tried getting a handle to the QTreeWidget's underlying *model()*, then connecting to its *rowsMoved* signal, but it doesn't seem to be emitted during internal moves.

I reimplemented QTreeWidget's *dropEvent()*, but there's no way to determine the destination row index there.

The *dropMimeData()* event doesn't get called at all for internal moves, apparently.

Any other approach I could try? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the reimplemented `dropEvent()`, you should be able to find the destination row index and item:

```
void
subclass::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event)
{
  QModelIndex index = indexAt(event->pos());
  if (!index.isValid()) {  // just in case
    event->setDropAction(Qt::IgnoreAction);
    return;
  }
  QTreeWidgetItem* destination_item = itemFromIndex(index);
  ....
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the recovered index points to the item under the mouse cursor, not the row indicated by the drop indicator. Move it a bit up, you get the item above, move it down, you get the one below, while the drop indicator stays in place. :(

Comment: @neuviemeporte: it didn't appear to be a problem for my own use case, but maybe that's what `dropIndicatorPosition()` is for.

Comment: Perfect. Didn't notice that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The OP actually asked how to get notified about an *internal move*, that is how to do it without sub-classing QTreeWidget (at least that's how I use *internal move* since it's built-in functionality). I just found a way it can be done: connect to the QTreeWidget model's [rowsInserted()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal!

```
connect(treeWidget->model(), SIGNAL(rowsInserted(const QModelIndex &, int, int)), this, SLOT(rowsInserted(const QModelIndex &, int, int)));
```

Comment: Does that also working with moving, instead of just when copying?

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, I figured out an another way to find out which element moved exactly where, which sidesteps the whole *dropIndicatorPosition()* and the associated *itemAbove(), itemBelow()* mess, or may at least help somewhat in supplementing it when moving items between different parents:

```
void MyTreeWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    // get the list of the items that are about to be dragged
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> dragItems = selectedItems();

    // find out their row numbers before the drag
    QList<int> fromRows;
    QTreeWidgetItem *item;
    foreach(item, dragItems) fromRows.append(indexFromItem(item).row());

    // the default implementation takes care of the actual move inside the tree
    QTreeWidget::dropEvent(event);

    // query the indices of the dragged items again
    QList<int> toRows;
    foreach(item, dragItems) toRows.append(indexFromItem(item).row());

    // notify subscribers in some useful way
    emit itemsMoved(fromRows, toRows);
}
```